# php script for dynamic redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cloaking

I've been searching for a php script which does dynamic url redirect, but could not find any.
Does anyone know a good one? I want to track outgoing clicks and to transform outgoing urls into this: website/go/feedtitleID

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpZ1g.jpg

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you need [Human readable URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL)? If not please give a more detailed explanation and examples

Comment: I've added a image to my original post. Hope it's clear?

Comment: Not really. If [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) is what you are trying to achieve, you won't get help here.

Comment: I don't think so. I think is url redirection what I need.

Comment: Check mod_rewrite in Apache. This module is used normally for URL rewriting

Comment: this seems to be a little complicated and would not track clicks. It would be great a straight out the box solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use header function for dynamic redirection.
For example,

```
header("Location: example.com");
exit();
```

Always use exit() or die() after header function to prevent execute below script.

Comment: Thanks but this won't do it as I have a page with several urls.